# Add last element to ArrayList before populating it

Tags: java, arraylist

```
final int k = 9;
final List<A> as = new ArrayList<A>(k + 1);
as.set(k, new A());
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    as.add(new A());
}
```

I need to create a list, then add the last element, after that add all the elements from the beginning up to the last element which was added first time. No I can not add it in the end. Is it right way todo that?

Comment: Did you try to run it?

Comment: Why don't you run it and see?

Comment: i don't understand why you would want to do such a thing

Comment: do one thing Please run it , i doesn't think anything wrong here

Comment: What makes me wonder is _why_ you want to do such a thing. If you just have to do it like that then you better do it... *shrug*.

Answer (score 1):

No it definitely won't work. The constructor

```
new ArrayList<A>(k + 1)
```

only tells the resulting list to have a **capacity** of `k + 1`. The new list still have a **size** of 0. Thus the next statement

```
as.set(k, new A());
```

will immediately throw IndexOutOfBoundsException.

---

If I were you, I'd simply save the value and add it at the end, assuming that `new A()` call has a side-effect which forces you to fill in the last element first (which itself is a bad idea):

```
final A lastA = new A();
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    as.add(new A());
}
as.add(lastA);
```

Alternatively, create an array with that fixed size, and convert that into a list (note that the result is not an ArrayList and cannot be resized):

```
final A[] aa = new A[k + 1];
aa[k] = new A();
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++ i) {
    aa[i] = new A();
final List<A> as = Arrays.asList(aa);
```